# Django redirect не работает

Tags: html, ajax, django, url, redirect

У меня есть мини сайтик django+ajax, когда я пытаюсь сделать обычный редирект, он не делается)

(Библиотеки все подключены)
Вот вьюшка:

```
def javascript(request):
    if request.POST:
        name = request.POST['name']
        print(name)
        return redirect('/')
    else:
        print("First")
        return render(request, 'javascript.html', {'title':'javascript'})
```

вот javascript.html:

```
    <label for="id_name">Имя: </label>
    <input type="text" name="name" id="id_name" placeholder="Имя..."><br>
    <label for="id_password">Пароль: </label>
    <input type="password" name="password" id="id_password" placeholder="Пароль..."><br>
    <label for="id_repassword">Повторите пароль: </label>
    <input type="password" name="repassword" id="id_repassword" placeholder="Повторите пароль..."><br>
    <input type="button" id="id_button" name="button" onclick="valid()">


<script>
function valid(form)
{
    name = $('#id_name').val();
    password = $('#id_password').val();
    repassword = $('#id_repassword').val();
    $.ajax({
        url:'/javascript/',
        method:'POST',
        cache:true,
        data:{'name':name, 'password':password, 'repassword':repassword,'csrfmiddlewaretoken': '{{ csrf_token }}'},
        //success: function(data){alert("Success!")}
    });
}
</script>
```

вот index.html:

```
<a href="javascript/">Let's Go!</a>
```

P.S. вопрос все еще открыт!

Comment: И success при этом выводил? (Вы его закомментировали почему-то)

Comment: Попробуйте другой адрес для `redirect` задать или имя view. Попробуйте поставить аргумент `permanent` в `Trie`

Comment: success да выводил и в терминале написано что переход на главную с кодом 200

Answer (score 1):

Нужно воспользоваться reverse https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/ref/urlresolvers/#django.urls.reverse

в urls.py:

```
url('/', view='index', name='url_name')
```

во views.py:

```
def javascript(request):
       if request.POST:
          name = request.POST['name']
          print(name)
          return redirect(reverse('url_name'))
       else:
          print("First")
          return render(request, 'javascript.html', {'title':'javascript'})
```